# How to implement a generic c# interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, azure-table-storage

I am having trouble understanding what my issue is here.
[CS0452 error, The type T must be ref type in order to use as a parameter...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0452?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0452))

The error is on this line:
`Response<T> tableEntity = TC.GetEntity<T>(pk, rk);`

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;

namespace AzureDataTables
{
    public class AzureDataTables<T> : IAzureDataTables<T> where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        ITableEntity GetTableEntity(string pk, string rk);
    }

    public class AzureDataTables<T> : IAzureDataTables<T> where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        public T GetTableEntity(string pk, string rk)
        {
            var tableEntity = TC.GetEntity<T>(pk, rk);
            return tableEntity.Value;
        }
        public TableServiceClient TSC { get; set; } = new TableServiceClient("");
        public TableClient TC => TSC.GetTableClient("");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This error occurs when you pass a value type such as a struct or int as a parameter to a generic type or method that has a reference type constraint."*

Comment: Please try by changing `return tableEntity;` to `return tableEntity.Value`;

Comment: @GauravMantri: That's not going to work.  This is an error that occurs *at compile time,* on the line of code above the one you're referencing.

Comment: Yes, @RobertHarvey that is the link I posted.  I am trying to figure out how to solve my problem.

Comment: @GauravMantri Good point, but the compiler error is in the line above the return statement.  TC.GetEntity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a concrete type in the implementation of the Interface if it has a generic type in it's contract.  Here's a working example:

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;

namespace AzureDataTables
{
    public interface IAzureDataTables<T> where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        ITableEntity GetTableEntity(string pk, string rk);
    }

    public class AzureDataTables<T> : IAzureDataTables<T> where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        public ITableEntity GetTableEntity(string pk, string rk)
        {
            Response<T> tableEntity = TC.GetEntity<T>(pk, rk);
            return tableEntity.Value;
        }

        public TableServiceClient TSC { get; set; } = new TableServiceClient("");
        public TableClient TC => TSC.GetTableClient("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited based on your edited question @terrence

Comment: Thank you Bron.  That did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

[`TableClient.GetEntity<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.getentity?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-getentity-1(system-string-system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) has these constraints on the generic type:

```
where T : class, ITableEntity, new();
```

You're missing the `class` constraint on your own generic type as well to be able to use it with that function.

Comment: Thank you for our assist Blindy.  I am giving @Connor some more comments about the new error after changes.

Comment: Your code would compile as is if you use an up to date VS 2022, C# 9 or 10, one of the two, added covariant return types. And since `T` at least implements `ITableEntity`, returning `T` will fulfil the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The methode you are calling is [TableClient.GetEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.getentity?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-getentity-1(system-string-system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) this has  a constraint `where T : class, Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity, new();`.
Your methode does not have the constraint `class` so when the compiler checks if your `T` can be used for the methode it does not comply with all the constraints.

If you change

```
public class AzureDataTables<T> : IAzureDataTables<T> where T : ITableEntity, new()
```

To

```
public class AzureDataTables<T> : IAzureDataTables<T> where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
```

It will compile.

Comment: Thank you Connor.  I have made changes to my code in the OP.  It is choking on the fact that I am not implementing the interface because GetTableEntity does not return ITableEntity.  Struggling here with generics a little beyond my brain power :)